# Run Spring Boot server and HttpServer on single application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have `init` method which starts `HttpServer` with controller:

```
public void init() {
    
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer("some_host", 8080);

        server.registerController(WorkshopOrderEndpoint.class);

        ControllerFactory.createController();

        server.startServer();
}
```

This is the **GatewayServer.class**:

```
public class GatewayServer {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(GatewayServer.class);

    private final String serverHost;

    private final String serverPort;

    private URI address;

    private ResourceConfig resourceConfig = null;

    private com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer server;

    public GatewayServer(final String host, final Integer port) {
        serverHost = host;
        serverPort = String.valueOf(port);

        try {
            logger.info("HTTP: Create Http-Server.");
            resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();

            address = new URI(String.format("http://%s:%s/", serverHost, serverPort));

        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            logger.error("HTTP: %s", ex.getMessage());
            LoggingHelper.sendExceptionLog(ex, "STATUS_URI_ERROR", "URI Encoding error.");
        } catch (ProcessingException ex) {
            logger.error("HTTP: %s", ex.getMessage());
            LoggingHelper.sendExceptionLog(ex, "STATUS_HTTP_ERROR", "HTTP-Server start error.");
        }

    }

    public void registerController(Class<?> controller) {
        if (resourceConfig != null) {
            logger.info("HTTP: Register Controller: %s", controller.getName());
            resourceConfig.register(controller);
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(address, resourceConfig, false);
        logger.info("HTTP: Start Http-Server. Adress: %s", address);
        server.start();
    }

    public void stopServer(int delay) {
        logger.info("HTTP: Stop Http-Server. Address: %s", address);
        server.stop(delay);
    }
}
```

This is pure java application and I want to start Spring Server in order to run `Eureka Server` by adding this code to the `init()` method:

```
 SpringRestApplication springRestApplication = new SpringRestApplication();
    springRestApplication.start();
```

Where **SpringRestApplication.class** is starting the Spring Boot server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class SpringRestApplication {

    public void start() {
        
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRestApplication.class, new String[0]);
    }
}
```

I would to run two servers on same host but different ports is it possible to connect `Spring Boot Tomcat server` with `HttpServer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the two on different ports.

Eugene shows a couple of options to change the port of the Spring Boot application: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port

This is the most straight-forward:

```
public void start() {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringRestApplication.class);
    app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
      .singletonMap("server.port", "8083"));
    app.run(args);
}
```

Comment: Changing port is not a problem. Problem is rewriting huge application which is not Spring and adding there Eureka Server (Spring Boot).

Comment: Do you want to run the Eureka Server in the same process? Eureka Servers are typically standalone processes, I'd think.

Comment: I would to run in same application those two.

Comment: No, the problem is HttpServer doesn't receive incoming requests when I put SpringApplication.run() before GatewayServer start or when I put SpringApplication.run() after GatewayServer, Tomcat doesn't start. The port on Tomcat is fine. But may be they should run in parallel?

Comment: You should check if SpringApplication.run() launches tomcat in a background thread or not, and if the method ends or not... And ask a specific question on that if you want answers.